# Деепричастие или деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

*Среди игроков на Су-27 оказалось какое-то огромное число любителей пускать ракеты через ОЛС по первому же обнаруженному контакту, **не разбираясь**, союзник это, или неприятель.*

Во-первых, одиночное ли это деепричастие или все-таки деепричастный оборот с зависимыми словами *союзник это, или неприятель*? Во-вторых, запятая перед *или*, к месту ли она (разделяет две грамматические основы: *союзник* и *неприятель*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Среди игроков на Су-27 оказалось какое-то огромное число любителей пускать ракеты через ОЛС (как?) **по первому же обнаруженному контакту, не разбираясь**, союзник это или неприятель.

Выделены однородные обстоятельства (падежная форма и деепричастие), бессоюзная связь, ставится запятая.

***Не разбираясь*** ― деепричастие, к которому относится придаточное предложение "это союзник или неприятель". **Это** ― подлежащее, **союзник или неприятель** ― однородные сказуемые, связанные одиночным союзом ИЛИ, поэтому нет запятой.